# Hint: There is a column named "pma_timestamp" in table "table_a", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query

Tags: postgresql, insert

I want to use a user defined function so that while inserting values in column i want to insert last_day of the month in one column by referencing other column in same table.

my code is-

```
insert into table_A
(id,pma_timestamp,monthend)
values
(103,'2017-08-15',last_day(pma_timestamp));
```

but getting the error:

> Hint: There is a column named "pma_timestamp" in table "table_a", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query

how to resolve this

Comment: hi can i use the column of the same table to populate the other column of the same table with some function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a column if the target table in the `values()` clause. You will need to repeat the value you provided for that column:

```
insert into table_A
(id, pma_timestamp, monthend)
values
(103, '2017-08-15', last_day('2017-08-15'));
```

If you don't want to repeat the value, you could write an INSERT trigger that populates the `monthend` column. Then you wouldn't need to provide a value for it at all.

---

In a relational database, it's usually not a good idea to store data that can easily be derived from existing values. The `monthend` column is such a derived attribute. I would not store it at all, because calculating it from `pma_timestamp` can easily be done during a SELECT query. If you don't want to repeat the calculation, create a view that provides that information.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to avoid repetition of the same value in such scenarios.

#### Method 1. Reword the `INSERT` statement

You could restate your `INSERT` request e.g. like this:

```
INSERT INTO
  table_A (id, pma_timestamp, monthend)
SELECT
  new_id, new_timestamp, last_day(new_timestamp)
FROM
  (VALUES (103, '2017-08-15')) AS v (new_id, new_timestamp)
;
```

Basically, in the process of inserting the values, you are assigning each one a name, which then allows you to reference them multiple times if necessary. In this case, the value `'2017-08-15'` is assigned the name `new_timestamp`, and that name is then used (inserted) both by itself and as part of the expression `last(new_timestamp)`.

#### Method 2. Redefine the `monthend` column

If the `monthend` value is supposed to always be the result of `last_day(pma_timestamp)`, you can redefine it as a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html).  Presumably you will need to first drop the existing `monthend` column first:

```
ALTER TABLE
  table_A
DROP COLUMN
  monthend
;
```

and then add it back as a generated column. For the purpose of the following example, the column's date type is assumed to be `timestamp`:

```
ALTER TABLE
  table_A
ADD
  monthend timestamp GENERATED ALWAYS AS (LAST_DAY(pma_timestamp)) STORED
;
```

And now you do not need to insert anything into `monthend`. Just insert the values into `pma_timestamp`, and `monthend` will be calculated automatically.

```
INSERT INTO
  table_A (id, pma_timestamp)
VALUES
  (103, '2017-08-15')
;
```